# Array sorting: all possible sequences

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array:

```
[
    [3, 1],
    [3, 3],
    [2, 2],
    [0, 0],
    [1, 3]
]
```

When I sort this array by (i[0] + i[1]), I get this:

```
[
    [3, 3],
    [3, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [0, 0]
]
```

I want to take first 2 elements from this array, but as you can see, there are actually no differences b/w [3, 1], [2, 2] and [1, 3]. The only reason why [3, 1] was sorted as 2nd is that it has a smaller index in the original array. So I want all possible sortings (6 arrays in that case), each having a different item on 2nd place.

How can I make this possible?

**Edit:**

Sort function:

```
(a,b) => (b[0]+b[1]) - (a[0]+a[1]));
```

Expected output:

```
[
    [
        [3, 3],
        [3, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [1, 3],
        [0, 0]
    ],
    [
        [3, 3],
        [3, 1],
        [1, 3],
        [2, 2],
        [0, 0]
    ],
    [
        [3, 3],
        [2, 2],
        [1, 3],
        [3, 1],
        [0, 0]
    ],
    [
        [3, 3],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 1],
        [1, 3],
        [0, 0]
    ],
    [
        [3, 3],
        [1, 3],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 1],
        [0, 0]
    ],
    [
        [3, 3],
        [1, 3],
        [3, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [0, 0]
    ],
]
```

Comment: can you show ... a) your sort function you use now, and b) your expected results

Comment: since your output is A,B,C,D,E ... you don't want 3 outputs, you want 6 - because B,C and D are all `4` ... so A,B,C,D,E ... A,B,D,C,E ... A,C,B,D,E ... A,C,D,B,E ... A,D,B,C,E and  ... A,D,C,B,E ... at least, that's what I can figure

Comment: @JaromandaX you are right. Since I just focus on the 2nd item, I missed that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

- build groups first with same sorting weights,
- build permutations of same groups and
- then get cartesian product out of the arrays.

```js
function permutation(array) {
    function p(array, temp) {
        var i, x;
        if (!array.length) {
            result.push(temp);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            x = array.splice(i, 1)[0];
            p(array, temp.concat([x]));
            array.splice(i, 0, x);
        }
    }

    var result = [];
    p(array, []);
    return result;
}

function cartesian(array) {
    function c(part, index) {
        array[index].forEach(function (a) {
            var p = part.concat([a]);
            if (p.length === array.length) {
                return r.push(p);
            }
            c(p, index + 1);
        });
    }

    var r = [];
    c([], 0);
    return r;
}

var array = [[3, 1], [3, 3], [2, 2], [0, 0], [1, 3]],
    groups = Object
        .values(array.reduce(
            (r, a) => ((r[a[0] + a[1]] = r[a[0] + a[1]] || []).push(a), r),
            Object.create(null)
        ))
        .reverse()
        .map(permutation),
    result = cartesian(groups).map(c => c.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []));
    
console.log(result.map(a => a.map(b => b.join())));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I thought there would be a simpler way, but I think this is what it is :) Thank you!